cannot startup my springboot fatjar after unpackage then packge using jar -xf a.jar then jar cf0M a.jar BOOT-INF META-INF org
ubuntu 15.8 
spring.boot.version: 2.7.14

I unpackaged my springboot fatjar , using the bellow cmd:
jar -xf a.jar 

then i packged it again, using:
jar cf0M a.jar BOOT-INF META-INF org

And then I started it up:
java -jar a.jar

But it failed with the following error :
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'codegenTableController' method 
cn.luo.yudao.module.infra.controller.admin.codegen.CodegenTableController#listByIds(Collection)
to {GET [/admin-api/infra/codegenTable]}: There is already 'codegenTableController' bean method
cn.luo.yudao.module.infra.controller.admin.codegen.CodegenTableController#exportExcel(Object, HttpServletResponse) mapped.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
        at cn.luo.yudao.ServerApplication.main(ServerApplication.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'codegenTableController' method 
cn.luo.yudao.module.infra.controller.admin.codegen.CodegenTableController#listByIds(Collection)
to {GET [/admin-api/infra/codegenTable]}: There is already 'codegenTableController' bean method
cn.luo.yudao.module.infra.controller.admin.codegen.CodegenTableController#exportExcel(Object, HttpServletResponse) mapped.
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.validateMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:669)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:332)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:420)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$2(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:299)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:297)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:266)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:225)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:205)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
        ... 24 common frames omitted




I did not put two class with the same name in the classpath for sure, absolutely.
The fatjar of a.jar can run correctly. But cannt run after unpackage then packge again which i used to do it in other Redhat environment, ( of course， it not the same fatjar) ,  It appears to be a classpath problem.
it's wield that the it works in my laptop of windows 11.
have tried to do the same thing in  my laptop of windows 11, and it works.

One question arises, why? Why unpack and repack?

What the hell wrong the the fatjar (  as i did nothing but just  unpackage then packge it again  )?   Or it that ubuntu 15.8  cant support i doing this ?  but why Redhat can do this.

Actually， I want to unpack the fatjar and  replace one class in the  BOOT-INF/classes/  to fix a bug, and then  repack it again to test it， since the fatjar  a.jar is too big size of some 300M.   @M.Deinum

Ehrm. Just fix the source and rebuild the artifact? As the classes in BOOT-INF/classes are your own. Not sure why you cannot just recompile the class and recreate the artifact. This seems a very cumbersome way to fix things.
